# jQuery UI Tabs, transform GET params into POST params

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a jQuery Ajax tabs:

```
<div id='tabs'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/echo/html/?html=1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/echo/html/?html=2">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/echo/html/?html=3">Tab3</a></li>
        <li><a href="/echo/html/?html=4">Tab4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

$('#tabs').tabs({
    ajaxOptions:{
        type: 'post',
        data:{
            html:'<p>sample html content</p>'
        }
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pJ9e/2/) demo

I successfully turned default ajax GET requests into POST requests, now what I want is to make the (HTML) GET param a POST param.
Anyone have any tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue!
the solution is to reset ajaxOptions on select event! now it works

```
<div id='tabs'>
    <ul>
        <li><a title="1" href="/echo/html/" data-html="1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a title="2" href="/echo/html/" data-html="2">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a title="3" href="/echo/html/" data-html="3">Tab3</a></li>
        <li><a title="4" href="/echo/html/" data-html="4">Tab4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {        
        var postVars = {
            html: $(ui.tab).attr('title'),
        };
        $(ui.tab).parent().parent().parent().tabs( "option", "ajaxOptions", { type:'post', data:postVars } );
    },
    ajaxOptions:{
        type: 'post',
        data:{
            html:$('#tabs a:first').attr('title')
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
            alert("Error occured");
        }
    }
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9pJ9e/7/

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can specify "data" fields in each tab and you can use it in ajax post;

```
<div id='tabs'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/echo/html/" data-html="1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/echo/html/" data-html="2">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/echo/html/" data-html="3">Tab3</a></li>
        <li><a href="/echo/html/" data-html="4">Tab4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

var postVars = {};
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        postVars = {
            param: $(ui.tab).data('html'),
        };
    },
    ajaxOptions:{
        type: 'post',
        data:postVars,
        error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
            alert("Error occured");
        }
    }
});
```

You can have a look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pJ9e/3/) demo

Comment: actually, this doesn't work..
to make things simpler, I used title attribute instead
I think on select event, only postVars changes, but ajaxOptions  are already set...
http://jsfiddle.net/9pJ9e/5/

Comment: Thanks for your tip, actually you helped me thinking about the **select** event

Comment: Yeah, as you specified in demo, you can use any other attribute like "title"